# The Uncommon Factor Number

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

*Based on a [chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39355755#39355755)*

### The Challenge

Given an input number \$n > 9\$, construct its reverse, ignoring leading zeros. Then, construct a list of all prime factors that the number and its reverse *don't* have in common. Multiply those factors together to create the ***Uncommon Factor Number*** of the input.

Or, to put it another way: if \$\text{rev}(n)\$ denotes the decimal reversal of integer \$n\$, calculate the product of \$n\$ and \$\text{rev}(n)\$ divided by the square of the \$\gcd(n, \text{rev}(n))\$.

Output that number.

#### Worked examples

For example, \$2244\$ reverses to \$4422\$. The prime factors of the first are \$[2, 2, 3, 11, 17]\$ and the prime factors of the reverse are \$[2, 3, 11, 67]\$. The numbers not in common multiplicities are \$[2, 17, 67]\$, so \$2278\$ is the output.

For another example, \$1234\$ reverses to \$4321\$. The product is \$5332114\$ and the GCD is \$1\$, so the output is \$5332114\$.

### Further clarifications

Obviously a palindromic number will have all its factors in common with its reverse, so in such a case the output is \$1\$ \$\left(\frac{n\times n}{n^2}\right)\$. Obviously, it's also possible for the output to be the multiplication all factors (i.e., the gcd is \$1\$ -- the input and its reverse are co-prime), as in the case of the \$1234\$ example.

### Rules

- The input and output can be assumed to fit in your language's native integer type.
- The input and output can be given [in any convenient format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- If possible, please include a link to an online testing environment so other people can try out your code!
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

### Examples

```
in
out

17
1207

208
41704

315
1995

23876
101222302
```

Comment: Can we assume the input will not have leading zeros?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Huh? You mean trailing zeroes?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No, leading zeros is exactly what I mean. Also

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, that's a safe assumption, given that you're given a number, and we generally don't write numbers with leading zeros anyway?

Comment: The second test case should be `1995` (I believe)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes. Don't know how I messed that one up.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Then my Jelly answer is valid :p

Comment: Perhaps add a test case where some factor is repeated after the symmetric difference. An initial version of my answer failed at that

Comment: For example `208 -> 41704`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. Good addition.

Comment: Is string input allowed? Like, with quotes?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sure, that's standard.

Comment: so you can take the input as a list of digits?

Comment: @Jonah Sure, that's allowed. Input/Output isn't the interesting part of this challenge, so I'm pretty flexible.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

#### Code

```
Â‚D¿÷P
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cNOjhlkuh/Yf3h7w/7@xoSkA)

#### Explanation

```
Â‚        # Get the array [input, reversed(input)]
  D       # Duplicate that array
   ¿      # Calculate the GCD of the array
    ÷     # Divide each element in the array by the GCD
     P    # Product of that array
```

Comment: A nice, simple alternative to the formula provided in the challenge - +1. Tried the same in Japt but it came out 2 bytes longer than what I already had.

Answer (score 5):

## J, 18 bytes

```
".@|.@":(*%*:@+.)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk9BSc@hRs9ByUpDS1XLykFbTzOWiys1OSNfIU3B0MjYBJldoeDnpKdQWpyqkFpRkpqXkpqiUFCUmpxZnJmfp5CZplCZX6qQkp@nXqJQnphXolCcnKmQl1@SWAKUhhljZGABYxobmv7/DwA)

Alternatively (credit to @Adnan's approach for the second one),

```
".@|.@":(*%2^~+.)]
".@|.@":*/@(,%+.)]
```

## J, 15 bytes (@miles's solution)

```
*/@(,%+.)|.&.":
```

## Explanation

This is just a straightforward implementation of the algorithm given by the OP.

```
".@|.@":(*%*:@+.)]
                 ]  n (input)
".@|.@":            n reversed
         *          Product of the two
          %         Divided by
              +.      GCD
           *:         Squared
```

## Explanation, @miles's solution

Very clever.

```
*/@(,%+.)|.&.":
         |.&.":  Reverse digits
           &.":   Convert to string, apply next function, and undo conversion
         |.       Reverse
   (,%+.)        Divide n and reverse(n) by GCD of both
*/               Product
```

Comment: 15 bytes with ``*/@(,%+.)|.&.":``

Comment: @miles I love the under trick

Comment: @miles that one is really slick.

Comment: Why not submit the 15 byte version as your main solution?

Comment: @Shaggy Not sure. My inclination was to respond with "it's significantly different from my own," but it's really just two optimizations. I'll get to updating it later.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
#(s=IntegerReverse@#)/GCD[#,s]^2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfWaPY1jOvJDU9tSgotSy1qDjVQVlT393ZJVpZpzg2zkjtf0BRZl6JgkNatJGxhblZ7P//AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
,ṚḌµ:g/P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/n4c5ZD3f0HNpqla4f8P//f0NzAA)

Comment: Dammit, I had exactly the same (except `DU` instead of `Ṛ`)

Comment: @ETHproductions Yeah `Ṛ` on an integer reverses the digits but doesn't convert back to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>108</s> 89 bytes

*-19 bytes thanks to plannapus for his gcd algorithm*

```r
function(n){k=1:nchar(n)-1
q=1:n
(r=sum(n%/%10^k%%10*10^rev(k)))*n/max(q[!r%%q&!n%%q])^2}
```

This will attempt to allocate at least one vector of size `4*n` bytes (and I think as many as 4), so this will throw a memory error for sufficiently large `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcjRCoJAEIXhe59CLzZmBHFnRDejfZJIEGkpFifcMoLo2bcNb37Od0J0@bGKbpXpebsLCH68pYNM1zEkVJQtf2YQ7GOdQVStSA9epZZphMsLPCKWUs/jG5ZTEZRadoWknnHgb3RABnNrc2JtMgcNtRv7vk3kZm@67dDEzI3m@AM)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>67</s> <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

So many bytes just to reverse the number :(

Takes input as a string. 1 byte saved thanks to l4m2.

```javascript
f=(n,x=n,y=r=[...n].reverse().join``)=>y?f(n,y,x%y):n*r/x/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrRCoIwFADQ9z5DCLZY10xSEW59SASK3YUid3Ensn398jl8PZypX3s/yPhdzuzelJJFxSYgm4iCTwDgFwitJJ6UhsmN3HUa7/FhtxdNOEbd8knykIc0OPZuJpjdR1mVFXWm9eEPr5dmR8vitnfLpq42Tz8)

Comment: `n*r/x/x`?aaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
f x|r<-read$reverse$show x=x*r`div`gcd x r^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDkAwFAXQrdxBR1IJFZ8BKxGi0YfGN69CB/Ze5yzarbRtIUzwH9cxkzaC6SF2JNxyvvCNj3gw9hnm0cCDexV2bQ80uNgeNwR2fWFCm5ZSJZXM0lyqrCqLLvw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>73</s> 68 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*

```python
import math
def f(n):g=int(str(n)[::-1]);print(n*g/math.gcd(n,g)**2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BboMwDIbveQqLCwSlnShaOzGx@56h6iEjTogECUtCpT49c0CaT7/9f/ptL680etduRVGwbw0Bn5XjoND5hBHSiKQHO8spWxgiCa/BuoQGAzgBg5yGdZIJd3gJXq1DyowD6dR/oH1ahQp@XjsWf1cZMFO5M4OqKOlA@ZnRLZudFx8SzDKNTKEGTVZnelpcxRSouXfdqXnwzyXkmavNW2bPR5bhdX3hG72QIvRwb24C2uZdwKX9uF0fjGkfwNIbsCMdA6ojyQooT19QCkA6v4ey5LurK8u3Pw)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDKyU1TSFNI0/TKtU2M69Eo7ikCMiJtrLSNYzVtC4oAonlaaXqg9TqpSenaKTq5GlqaRlp/k/TMDY01fwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
/*QKs_`Q^iKQ2
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%2aQKs_%60Q%5EiKQ2&input=123&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=17%0A315%0A23876&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

This uses Adnan's approach and takes input as a String.

```
KsM_BQ*Fm/diFKK
```

**[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KsM_BQ%2aFm%2FdiFKK&input=%22315%22&debug=0)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
sw
*V/yU ²
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=CnN3CipWL3lVILI=&input=MTIzNA==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`. The empty line at the beginning, prevents the following line from overwriting `U`

```
sw
```

Convert `U` to a string (`s`), reverse it (`w`), convert back to an integer and assign to variable `V`.

```
*V
```

Multiply `U` by `V`.

```
/
```

Divide.

```
yU
```

GCD of `V` and `U`.

```
²
```

Squared. Implicit output of resulting integer.

---

### Alternative, 13 bytes

Just because I like being able to use `N`.

```
NpUsw)mxNry)×
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=TnBVc3cpbXpOcnkp1w==&input=MjA4)

Comment: Smart trick with GCD. I think that algorithm might actually be shorter than the current Jelly solution...

Comment: @ETHproductions In Jelly GCD ends up being longer...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I "have" an 8-byte version, but this involves dividing the results of two dyads and I'm not sure how to properly do that...

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
tVPU*1MZdU/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQsIFTL0DcqJVT//38jIxMTAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8kLCBUy9A3KiVU/79LyH9Dcy4jAwsuY0NTLiNjC3MzAA).

#### Explanation

```
t      % Imoplicit input: number. Duplicate
VPU    % String representation, flip, evaluate. This reverses digits
*      % Multiply input and reversed-digit version
1M     % Push the input and reversed-digit version again
Zd     % Greatest common divisor
U      % Square
/      % Divide. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 11 bytes

```
₁₁ᛦ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcqZOBuPtRU@OHuRNWA/FUCHMqULQHSC94OHsZkNn7/7@hOQA)

No GCD built-in. ;-;

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
S¤§÷o□⌋*i↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr//9TwqTCp8O3b@KWoeKMiypp4oaU////IjMxNSI)

-1 thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).
-1 thanks to [Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb).

Answer (score 1):

## x86 Machine Code, 39 bytes

```
;;; Obtain a "reversed" version of the input value.
;;; 
;;; To do this, each iteration of a loop, we take the input value modulo 10,
;;; add that to our accumulator (EDI), multiply the accumulator by 10, and
;;; divide the input value by 10. x86's DIV instruction does both modulo and
;;; division as a single operation, with the cost of clobbering two output
;;; registers (EAX and EDX). We clobber the input value throughout the loop
;;; (the way we know we're done is when it becomes 0---that means that we have
;;; pulled all of the digits off of it), so we need to save a copy of it first.
89 C8           mov    eax, ecx     ; make copy of input
31 FF           xor    edi, edi     ; clear accumulator
6A 0A           push   10
5E              pop    esi          ; set ESI to 10
             Reverse:
0F AF FE        imul   edi, esi     ; accumulator *= 10
99              cdq                 ; zero EDX in preparation for division
F7 F6           div    esi          ; EDX:EAX / 10 (EAX is quot, EDX is rem)
01 D7           add    edi, edx     ; accumulator += remainder
85 C0           test   eax, eax     ; was quotient 0?
75 F4           jnz    Reverse      ; if not, keep looping and extracting digits

;;; At this point, EAX is 0 (clobbered throughout the loop),
;;; ECX still contains a copy of our original input, and
;;; EDI contains the 'reversed' input.
89 C8           mov    eax, ecx     ; make another copy of the input
F7 E7           mul    edi          ; multiply input (implicit EAX operand)
                                    ;  by 'reversed', with result in EDX:EAX
                                    ;  (note: EDX will be 0)

;;; Compute the greatest common denominator (GCD) of the input and
;;; the 'reversed' values, using a subtraction-based algorithm.
             GCD_0:
39 CF           cmp    edi, ecx     ; compare the two values
72 02           jb     GCD_1        ; go to GCD_1 if less than
87 F9           xchg   ecx, edi     ; swap values
             GCD_1:
29 F9           sub    ecx, edi     ; subtract
75 F6           jnz    GCD_0        ; if sum != 0, go back to the top

;;; Square the GCD.
0F AF FF        imul   edi, edi

;;; Divide the product of input and 'reversed' by the square of the GCD.
;;; Remember from above that the product of input and 'reversed' is in
;;; the EAX register, and we can assume EDX is 0, so we don't need to do
;;; a CDQ here in preparation for the division. Using EAX as the implicit
;;; source operand saves us a byte when encoding DIV.
F7 F7           div    edi

;;; The DIV instruction placed the quotient in EAX,
;;; which is what we want to return to the caller.
C3              ret
```

The above function computes the "uncommon factor number" of the specified input parameter. Following the register-based [__fastcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall), the parameter is passed in the `ECX` register. The result is returned in the `EAX` register, as with all x86 calling conventions.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/baoNAEIav3acYLAUtTbOu0VVsAyGNL9Etsl1NsmA2RVdYKH312smJ5CIXP3P455th1GSj1DiqvektqK3swGXpcl83H5/wBr5wWS7cMhMujoQrS@HShXAUlawwYr1AlZjnOFdyVIp9nH3HPEuQpcJxjOXsuuswt0LFhxp5zpBBZQceeyw/xSOX3twpzzdQy9gvSG@l1QoG0@uNaWqoKmltp78G21RVEKxlb5Vs2zCE4An/Kp0Jg8twiP@dfy3GB21UO9QNvPa21vuX7ZwQbSzspDZBSH6I991hvQ58AIi4sJO5sI@1MP4znBYHRyMMC286hYhRfoswmt1H0Dgjs4jT2S0TR8l9Bo3LmTxPrgiLM57eQ47GBaERYyymjHjE6xo7dAZoQX7HP7Vu5aYfJ7uY/QM)**

This took an awfully long time to write in such a compact form, but it was a fun exercise. Lots of contortions to get the most optimal register scheduling possible, within the constraints of the x86 `DIV` instruction's implicit operands and trying to use short encodings of `MUL` and `XCHG` instructions whenever possible. I'd be very curious to see if someone can think of another way to shorten it further. My brain was quite fried by the end. Thank a compiler next time you see one! (Although this is *way* better code than what a compiler would generate... Especially if you tweaked it slightly without size constraints, removing things like `XCHG`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṚḌæl:gɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlkPd/QcXpZjlX5y@v/D7Y@a1vz/b2iuo2BkYKGjYGxoCmQZmZjoKBgaGQNJI2MLczMA)

-1 byte thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)

Similar to Erik's Jelly answer, but uses a dyadic route rather than monadic lists.

Uses the formula [found by ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233489/66833)

$$\text{UCF}(n) = \frac{\text{lcm}(n,\text{rev}(n))}{\gcd(n, \text{rev}(n))}$$

### How it works

```
ṚḌæl:gɗ - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ṛ       - Split n into digits and reverse
 Ḍ      - Convert back into an integer; rev(n)
      ɗ - Combine the previous three links into a dyad
           with n on the right and rev(n) on the left:
  æl    -   lcm(n,rev(n))
     g  -   gcd(n, rev(n))
    :   -   Divide lcm(n,rev(n)) by gcd(n, rev(n))
```

Comment: I must be missing something here since no one uses that approach, but with `a*b/gcd(a,b)=lcm(a,b)` this should work for 7 bytes: [`ṚḌæl:gɗ`](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef8Kw4fGrP/huZrhuIzDpmw6Z8mX/8OH4oKs//8yMjQ0LCAxMjM0)

Comment: @ovs I can't see any obvious problem with that, and it seems to work for all the test cases, nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
⊢(∧÷∨)⌽⍢⍕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HXIo1HHcsPb3/UsULzUc/eR72LHvVO/Z/2qG3Co96@R31TPf0fdTUfWm/8qG0ikBcc5AwkQzw8g/@nHVqhYGiuYGRgoWBsaKpgZGxhbgYA)

$$\text{UCF}(n) = \frac{n\times \text{rev}(n)}{\gcd(n, \text{rev}(n))^2} = \frac{\text{lcm}(n,\text{rev}(n))}{\gcd(n,\text{rev}(n))} = \frac{\text{lcm}}{\gcd}(n,\text{rev}(n))$$

`⌽` reverse `⍢` under `⍕` conversion to string, then apply `∧÷∨` (lcm ÷ gcd) between the result and and the original argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 bytes

```
ĐĐ₫Đ3Ș*↔Ǥ²/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9weXT//8SQxJDigqvEkDPImCrihpTHpMKyL///MjI0NA)

| Code | Stack | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Đ | n,n | Implicit input; duplicate top of stack |
| Đ | n,n,n | Duplicate top of stack |
| ₫ | n,n,rev(n) | Reverse the digits of the top of the stack |
| Đ | n,n,rev(n),rev(n) | Duplicate top of stack |
| 3Ș | n,rev(n),rev(n),n | Flip the order of the top three items on the stack |
| * | n,rev(n),rev(n)*n | Multiply the top two items on the stack |
| ↔ | rev(n)*n,rev(n),n | Flip the stack |
| Ǥ² | rev(n)*n,gcd(n,rev(n))^2 | Take the gcd of n and rev(n) and square it |
| / | rev(n)*n/(gcd(n,rev(n))^2) | Divide; implicit print |

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>158</s> <s>150</s> <s>148</s> <s>138</s> <s>125</s> <s>123</s> <s>116</s> 107 <s>+ 19</s> bytes

```
i->{int o,r,f,t=f=i;i=r=i.valueOf(""+new StringBuffer(t+"").reverse());while(t>0)t=i%(i=t);return f/i*r/i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY8xT8MwEIX3/IpTJCS7TV0EY3AGBiQGxNARMZjUDhcc23LOqaIqvz24kDednj7pfderSR180K4//6w4BB8J@tyJRGiFSa4l9E7s6qII6ctiC61V4whvCh1cC8gZSVHuXzb26dWR7nSsYDsamEHCiofmio7AV7EyFUkjsUYZJYpJ2aTfDSvLvdMXOFFE1z0nY3RktC9LLqKedBw147y@fKPVjJp7ThLvGEriddSUogNzxF08Yr2s2fZmthlvgpPHMwzZm/0vfHyCit3ItzduOc0j6UH4RCJkhNgsVAh2Zo8PefoPW4pl/QU)

Comment: In the while loop, you can replace `t!=0` by `t>0`, since t will never be negative. `f*r/(i*i)` is the same as `f/i*r/i`. You can drop `f=t;` and `r=i;` if you chain the assignment of `i` and `t`.

Comment: The while loop can be written as `while(t>0)t=i%(i=t);` (-11 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

Thanks to [i cri everytim](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68615/i-cri-everytim).

```python
def f(n):g=int(`n`[::-1]);print n*g/gcd(n,g)**2
from fractions import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsMgEEDRvaeYpYqlmNCmGHKSEEhJMnYWGUVn09Pb0L98/PyVT@Kutf1AQM0mxIlY9MrrHMLNL2bM5QJgG@9x2zW7aKztFJZ0Apb3JpS4Ap05FbFNjioVJpj94KD3Dwdd/xqei1KYChAQw38JCq5Qk2k/)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 77 bytes

Note that in Python 2, you cannot use the `math.gcd()` method, and you must do it "by hand".

```python
y=lambda a,b:b and y(b,a%b)or a
def f(n):g=int(`n`[::-1]);print n*g/y(n,g)**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwFAX3OcXbFBJJKSqtJSUnEcEfNGmg/Ypmk9OnobMchtlzem/clZLth75uIZB2xoF4QZZO08Wp7QCJZfXwkpUJNnKSM8@jMdd2Uq/9qALchFuWrINqmq6k9UwnLMZ20Ojbu0bXP4fHJISvt4jI@CdGoOJlVOUH)

Comment: Python 3 has `gcd` as `fractions.gcd`.

Comment: @icrieverytim That's why I chose to solve it in Python 2.

Comment: ...Whoops, I meant Python 2. Python 3 has `math.gcd`.

Comment: @icrieverytim done.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 72 bytes

71 bytes of code + 1 flag (`-p`)

```perl
$t=$_*($b=reverse);($_,$b)=(abs$_-$b,$_>$b?$b:$_)while$_-$b;$_=$t/$_**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvhBoAwFAbQl/l@bNmkSJTVo1xdLkVqtqm375b@Hk6UtHeqKAFUGXBIcknKYkcDcmAbzMIZ5MEONIFn8ACy97rt8vMICij116tWtemfM5btPLL6@AI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 8 bytes

```
_]FbP).^B
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=5F+5D+46+62+50+29+DE+42&input=%222244%22&warnings=0&hex=1)

Takes input as a string.

```
_         -    reversed(input)
 ]        -   [^, input]
  FbP)    -  for i in ^:
   b      -     int(^)
    P     -    factors(^)
      .^  -  xor_seq(^)
        B - product(^)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm/tree/v1), 9 bytes

```
DR«D]Æ┴/µ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fJejQapfYw22PpmzRP7T1/39DIwA)

Comment: psst... [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm/blob/master/components.md) is out and better than ever!

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
Ṙ∆Ŀ?Ḃġ/
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%98%E2%88%86%C4%BF%3F%E1%B8%82%C4%A1%2F&inputs=17&header=&footer=)

```
Ṙ       # Reverse
 ∆Ŀ     # LCM with that
   ?    # Take input
    Ḃ   # Dupe-reverse
     ġ  # GCD
      / # Quoitent
```

Would be [5 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%98%E2%82%8C%E2%88%86%C4%BF%C4%A1%2F&inputs=17&header=&footer=) if parallel apply worked with digraphs.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 25 bytes

Uses [ovs' technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142177/the-uncommon-factor-number/233489#233489).

```ruby
:/%[:lcm%r=S|:~|Z,:gcd%r]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBYjdbjaWlJWm6Fjut9FWjrXKSc1WLbINrrOpqonSs0pNTVItiIfKrNbkKFNyiDY2MTaAiCxZAaAA)

### Explanation

```
:/ % [:lcm % r = S | :~ | Z, :gcd % r]

             r = S | :~ | Z             # Helper function: Convert to string, reverse, convert back to int
:/ % [                     ,         ]  # Divide...
      :lcm % r                          #   LCM of input and its reverse by
                             :gcd % r   #   GCD of input and its reverse
```

### J-uby, 32 bytes

We can get rid of the awkward helper function `r` but at a cost of seven bytes:

```ruby
:/%(-[:%&:lcm,:%&:gcd]^(S|:~|Z))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWNxWs9FU1dKOtVNWscpJzdUB0enJKbJxGcI1VXU2UpiZE3coCBbdoQyNjk1gIf8ECCA0A)